# How to fix a java error where else without if

Tags: java

I'm making a bmi calculator and I can't make a proper if else statement. I don't understand the error in the else if part. It says that error 'else' without 'if'. what is the proper closing of the if-else statement.

```
  if (choices == ('e' || 'E'))
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR WEIGHT IN POUNDS(lb): ");
    weighte = input.nextDouble();
    System.print.out("ENTER YOUR HEIGHT IN FEET(ft): ");
    heighte = input.nextDouble();

    bmi = (weighte / (heighte * heighte));
   else if (choices == ('m' || 'M'));
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR WEIGHT IN KILOGRAMS(kg): ");
    weightm = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR HEIGHT IN CENTIMETERS(cm): ");
    heightm = input.nextDouble();
    bmi = (weightm / (heightm * heightm));

System.out.print("YOUR BMI IS " + bmi);
```

Comment: else if (choices == ('m' || 'M'));  why there's a semi colon here?

Comment: Use parantheses. "{}"! Without, the if statement ends at the first ";"

Comment: As previous comment says -> Java does not care about indentation or white-space in your code. You have to put statements in code blocks `{}`. There are languages that use whitespace/indentation (Python), but Java is not one of them.

Comment: Also the condition is seems very sketchy... you should go through some introductory tutorial.

Comment: I second @PavelHoral. My Java days have been gone a while but I really doubt `choices == ('m'||'M')` is valid java syntax

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think it is an exact duplicate. In that question, it was a semicolon right after the condition. Here, it is missing brackets, _as well as_ a semicolon. Does that count as dupe, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

If you write it without {}:

```
if (choices == ('e' || 'E'))
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR WEIGHT IN POUNDS(lb): "); // <-- if statement ends here
    weighte = input.nextDouble(); // <-- runs unconditionally
//...
else if (choices == ('m' || 'M')); // <-- if ends with ;
```

So, just use parantheses

```
if(condition){
// ...
} else if(condition) {
// ...
}
```

See also [Java Tutorials: if-else](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html):

> *In addition, the opening and closing braces are optional, **provided that the "then" clause contains only one statement**:*

( emphasis by me )

---

There are more issues with this code, which I partly think are due to taking a snippet from a bigger chunk of code. But I think this is the "main" issue here.

EDIT: One last thing...

If "e" and "m" are the *only two choices possible*, then just kick out the second if and condition. If it is not "e", then it has to be "m". As is, there is a theoretical possibility it's neither "e" nor "m" which leaves `bmi` unset (or set to default).